# trying to implement "imabsdiff" function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, scilab

I am trying to implement imabsdiff function in scliab , but i am getting different results, when i do it theoretically and using inbuilt functions

```
//Image subtraction with absolute difference and its effect
//Image 2 is being subtracted from image 1

clc;
clear;


//reading the image
A=ReadImage('E:\pruthvi iitb\DIP\Chapter 3 DIP\cocacola1.png');
B=ReadImage('E:\pruthvi iitb\DIP\Chapter 3 DIP\cocacola2.png');
A=RGB2Gray(A);
B=RGB2Gray(B);
figure(1);
ShowImage(A,'First Image');
title("First Image");

figure(2);
ShowImage(B,'Second Image');
title("Second Image");


[m n]=size(A);//size om image , M rows and N cols
//C=[][];//Absolute  Subtracted Image
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        a=A(i,j);
        b=B(i,j);
          C(i,j)=abs(a -b);// absolute difference


    end
end

figure(3);
ShowImage(C,'Absolute Subtracted Image');
title("Absolute Subtracted Image");
figure(4);
ShowImage(imabsdiff(A,B),'formula Image');
title("Absolute Subtracted Image");
```

Cocalcola1.png [image: Image A]
Cocacola2.png[image: Image 2]

results

right side using inbuilt function

[image: result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your issue is that you are trying to subtract `uint8` values from each other.  Since `uint8` can't be negative, when you do `a-b` (which will be calculated before it gets put into the `abs` function), you won't get the right answer for any case where b is larger than a.

Use `im2double` to convert your images to double, and `im2uint8` to convert them back.

Incidentally, you don't need to loop over pixels here. You can simply do (once the images have been cast to double):

```
C = abs(A-B)
```

Comment: This is the issue, I tried to debug it and came to the same conclusion.